# Algorithm Error: Argument cannot covert 1 from pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

In this assignment, I'm making an application where a user inputs a phone number whether it be letters or not.

I've tried using the const on maps or vector to see if it fixes the problem, but I think it just created more errors.

Here's the code that I think that causes some problems

```
std::vector<int> mappednums;
    for (char& achar : word) {
        auto itr = std::find_if(lookupmap.begin(), lookupmap.end(), [&](std::pair<int, std::vector<char>>& aPair)->bool
            {

                auto itr = std::find_if(aPair.second.begin(), aPair.second.end(), [&](char& ch) {
                    return ch == achar;
                    });

                if (itr != aPair.second.end()) {
                    return true;
                }
                });
        if (itr != lookupmap.end()) {
            mappednums.push_back(itr->first);
        }
```

I expected this to find a pair, but it gives me an error saying it cannot convert argument 1 from the code above. Here's the error:

```
'bool main::<lambda_06927067034dcc4076cc2514a7e290fe>::operator ()(std::pair<int,std::vector<char,std::allocator<char>>> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'std::pair<int,std::vector<char,std::allocator<char>>> &'
```

Comment: What type is `stringmap` and `lookupmap`?

Comment: We have to see more of (read: all of) the code; this cuts off in the middle of a function call.

Comment: stringmap is under std::map<std::vector<int>, std::string> stringmap, and lookup is std::map<int, std::vector<char>> lookupmap.

Comment: If you have additional details for the question, please edit them into it, don't comment.  Consider a [mcve].

Comment: In Visual Studio, the "Error" window just has summaries of the error. The full error message is in the "Output" window.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Add `const` before `int` in first lambda's parameter:

```
[&](std::pair<const int, std::vector<char>>& aPair)->bool
```

Long answer:

According to the [std::map reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) `map<K, V>::iterator` is an iterator to a `map<K, V>::value_type`, and `map<K, V>::value_type` is `pair<const K, V>` (is your case is `pair<const int, vector<char>>`).

The problem is that you try to bind `pair<int, vector<char>> &` reference to the values of type `pair<const int, vector<char>>`. If you could do so, you would be able to mutate the keys in a map, completely destroying map's internal structure. So you are not allowed to mutate them, and it is denoted as `const` in `pair<const int, vector<char>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the parameter correctly for your lambda.  It should be

```
[&](std::pair<const int, std::vector<char>>& aPair)
```

Note the `const int` as the first type of the pair.  The value type of a map (and what you get when you dereference a map iterator) has the first member of the pair constant, since changing the key value once it is the map can potentially break the sorting in the tree structure used to hold the map.

One way to avoid problems like this is to use

```
[&](LookupMapType::value_type &aPair)
```

(where 'LookupMapType' is the type of `lookupmap`).

If your compiler supports C++14 or later (and you enable it, if needed), you can simplify that some more to

```
[&](auto &aPair)
```